# diplaying user HTML and HTML spill-over

Tags: php, html

I am displaying user submitted HTML as part of a page (the user's resume). I noticed that if the user's HTML get's cut off in the DB, due to character limit, when the HTML is displayed, any tags that didn't get closed, spills over to the rest of the page.

Am I able to contain the HTML within a div? Another solution? I'm using PHP, by the way.

Thanks.

Comment: N.p that is what this site is for. Helping people :-) Thanks for accepting! Also, do you parse the HTML input (or output) to remove malicious code? It is very easy to do CSS attacks if you don't remove things like javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have one ore more unclosed tags in you HTML, your DOM becomes invalid and the consequences are unpredictable. Make sure that the submitted HTML doesn't get cut by using a TEXT column in your DB table.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't follow the last comment. How does using a TEXT column help? I believe my current issue is the character limiting. I'm currently using VARCHAR.

Comment: That is the point, VARCHAR can usually store at most 255 characters while TEXT is unlimited. Just change the column type to TEXT.

Comment: @satoshi TEXT is not unlimited. It has a hard limit of 65534 bytes. MEDIUMTEXT can hold 16777214 bytes and LONGTEXT can hold up to 4294967294 bytes. More information to be found here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html

Comment: Of course isn't not unlimited, it's just "unlimited" =P Keep in mind that the values you specified are dependent from the database and no one spoke about MySQL in the question (in fact since MySQL 5.0.3 the limit for VARCHAR is 65,535)

Comment: Yes. I'm using my MYSQL, and I have the character limit set to 10k for another field, I just wanted this to be smaller ideally. I didn't understand the TEXT recommendation as VARCHAR is essentially the same for me (relative to character limits). I was hoping there would some javascript or php solution that could close any unclosed tags. Thanks for the responses.

Comment: You can build your own tokenizer and close any opened tags at the end.